# Run function doesn't execute program

Tags: autoit

```
$pid = Run('"' & $executable & '"' & $flags & ' "' & $somefile & '"',  @SW_HIDE, $STDOUT_CHILD+$STDERR_CHILD)
```

The AutoIt Run() function doesn't work, `$pid` is set to 0 and `@error` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The `Run ( "program" [, "workingdir" [, show_flag [, opt_flag]]] )` function[[1]](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm) has a total of 4 parameters, if you leave out the `workingdir` by mistake then it will not work as expected and set `@error` to 1

The correct function call would have been:

```
$pid = Run('"' & $executable & '"' & $flags & ' "' & $somefile & '"', "",  @SW_HIDE, $STDOUT_CHILD+$STDERR_CHILD)
```

The working dir is not specified there, which is not recommended, but I did not require it for my use-case.